# Unexpected token < in JSON Content at position 0 Error

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I have what seems to be a valid JSON object according to jsonlint:

```
{"data":[{"name":"undefined - blablabla (undefined)"},{"name":"undefined - blablabla (undefined)"},{"name":"undefined - blablabla (undefined)"},{"name":"undefined - On blablabla (undefined)"}]}
```

however, I have the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Here is my react component:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/',    {
          method: 'GET',
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Accept': 'application/json' },
     credentials: 'same-origin'      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(user => this.setState({ data: data }));
  }
```

Here is how I'm sending the response from the server-side:

```
app.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
    request('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts?access_token=' + token,  
function (error, response, body) {
    let views = []
   JSON.parse(body).items.forEach(view => {
            views.push({
              name: view.webPropertyId + ' - ' + view.name + ' (' + view.websiteUrl + ')'
            })
          })
  console.log(JSON.parse(body).items);
  res.json({data:views});

});
    }
);
```

EDIT#1: I've updated the headers with `'Accept': 'application/json'`

Comment: Sounds like your `fetch` request is returning HTML. If you look at your **Network** tab and look at the **Response**, do you that you _actually_ are getting JSON back?

Comment: you are right. I got this: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` how do I return JSON?

Comment: You are fetching `/` I assume you started the project with `yarn start` so you should put your file in `public` and name it `hi.json` now you can fetch it with `fetch("hi.json")`

Comment: @HMR I've updated my question with server-side code

Comment: Err, most of the headers you're sending with that fetch are... well, wrong/unnecessary.

Comment: Are you running the project with webpack dev server? If so then I guess you open `localhost:3000/` you have to use another port to get to your express server

Comment: I have everything under one port only.

Comment: contentType isn't needed for GET Requests, as there's no body for the contentType to apply to. access-control headers don't need to be set client-side. and accept won't alter how node.js responds.

Comment: @KevinB you are right. I'd like to delete my question but I can't. Now I have a CORS policy issue which is a totally different issue.

Comment: Deleting your question is not required, it is a valid question that has been answered elsewhere :). I have marked it as a duplicate of that other answers, so that others with the same problem as you would be able to find the answer more easily. (If you think I have missed my mark on the duplicate, feel free to reply here or flag this question).